# Excel Vba create array from 2 cell values step size of 1

Tags: excel, vba, cell, step

I'm trying to create an array, that changes sizes, based on 2 cell values.
This array will then be used in a For loop.

For example:

```
B3 = 1 C3 = 4
```

I would like the array to have a Lowerbound of 1 and a Upperbound of 4 with step size or interval of 1

The code works when I type the array like below but I'd like it to be dynamic or changed based on the Cell values B3 and C3.

```
SheetList = Array("1", "2", "3", "4")
```

Answer (score 2):

just use a for loop:

```
 Sub workForFree()
 
 Dim sheetlist() As Variant
 ReDim sheetlist(ActiveSheet.Range("C3") - ActiveSheet.Range("B3"))
 
 Dim k As Long
 k = 0
 
 Dim i As Long
 For i = ActiveSheet.Range("B3") To ActiveSheet.Range("C3") Step 1
    sheetlist(k) = i
    k = k + 1
 Next i
 
 Debug.Print Join(sheetlist, ",")
    
    
 End Sub
```

Comment: LBound(sheetlist)=0 in your solution, not 1 as it's required. It should be: ReDim sheetlist(ActiveSheet.Range("C3"), ActiveSheet.Range("B3"))

Comment: No it equals 1. Run it with 1 in b3 and 4 in c3.

Comment: The array is ReDim'd with one number only in your code, which sets the UBound = 3 (4-1=3); Lbound=0 by default: you put a minus there, not a comma :)

Comment: That is correct, the OP wants a 1D array as output.  A 1D array with the numbers from the value in B3 to the Value in C3 so `{1,2,3,4}` in the OP's given example. so `sheetlist(0) = 1`,`sheetlist(1)=2`,`sheetlist(2)=3`, and `sheetlist(3)=4`

Comment: Q: "I would like the array to have a Lowerbound of 1 and a Upperbound of 4 with step size or interval of 1".    Well, if "SheetList = Array("1", "2", "3", "4")" then "Lbound(SheetList)=0". So what now...?

Comment: The OP was talking about the values in the array and not the array items when refering to the lowerbounds and upperbounds.

Comment: OK, so I clearly do not understand the terms "Lowerbound" and "Upperbound". NP, I can live with this :)

Answer (score 2):

If you dispose of version MS 365 you can use the new [`Sequence()` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) (which will be 1-based by default):

```
Sub CreateSequence365()
    Dim lo As Long: lo = ActiveSheet.Range("B3")    ' start of sequence
    Dim hi As Long: hi = ActiveSheet.Range("C3")    ' end   of sequence
    'create sequence via single code line
    Dim sheetlist: sheetlist = Application.Sequence(1, hi - lo + 1, lo, 1)
    'display results in VB Editor's immediate window
    Debug.Print "~~> " & Join(sheetlist, ","), _
          vbNewLine & "Boundaries: " & LBound(sheetlist) & " To " & UBound(sheetlist)
End Sub
```

**Result in VB Editor's immediate window:**

```
~~> 1,2,3,4   
Boundaries: 1 To 4
```

**Edit #1: Alternative approach by other versions:**

```
Sub CreateSequence()
    Dim lo As Long: lo = ActiveSheet.Range("B3")
    Dim hi As Long: hi = ActiveSheet.Range("C3")
    Dim sheetlist: sheetlist = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(" & lo & ":" & hi & ")"))
    Debug.Print "~~> " & Join(sheetlist, ","), _
          vbNewLine & "Boundaries: " & LBound(sheetlist) & " To " & UBound(sheetlist)
End Sub
```

Comment: When I try to step through the For Loop line by line the code always opens the last worksheet on the workbook, regardless of the sheet name.                                                                             
Its like its not interrupting the lower and upper bound but rather just jumps to the last sheet.  I can specify a range say LB= 18 UB=22 but the code just starts at the last sheet in the position on the workbook. However when use a defined array function like sheetlist = Array("18", "19", "20", "21", "22") the loop works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ross.P - There's no For loop in the above code - at which code line do you get issues? - Of course you could fully qualify your range references (e.g. `Sheet1.Range("...")` or `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`) instead of referencing `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Code gets stuck here `Worksheets(sheetlist(X)).Activate` If i use the `sheetlist = Array("18", "19", "20")` no issues but when trying to switch to `Dim lo As Long: lo = ActiveSheet.Range("B3")` & `Dim hi As Long: hi = ActiveSheet.Range("C3")` the code gets stuck and will not start at the lower bound

Comment: `For X = LBound(sheetlist) To UBound(sheetlist) Windows("Truck Log-East Gate-January.xlsx").Activate Worksheets(sheetlist(X)).Activate Range("A4:R4").Select Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select Selection.Copy Windows("Truck Racks RawData.xlsm").Activate Sheets("RawDataMacro").Select Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select ' moves cursor down one cell Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False Next X `

Comment: I don't know the occurring error message and the cited code goes far beyond the original post. IMO all answers solved your request to create a defined sequence, so you may consider to ask a new question with exact description together with some sample data. @Ross.P